# Validate input of a directory

Tags: ruby, validation

Their input should be a directory in c:\folder\subfolder\ format. Additionally I don't want it to try to run unless the directory contains .flv files. So it needs to exist AND contain .flv files. Otherwise it should ask the user to input another directory.

The code also cleans up the slashes, and adds a trailing slash, which I need for other parts of the program. What I have works when given a directory that exists and contains the .flv files, but if it doesn't contain .flv files it just ends the program instead of asking for additional input; meaning it porceeds as long as the directory exists, even if it doesn't have any .flv files.

```
def is_valid_dir()
    input = "nil"
    until File.directory?(input) && Dir.glob("#{input}*.flv")
        puts "Enter the full directory path of the flv files."
        input = gets.chomp
        if input[-1..-1] == '/'
            # Do nothing if it already 
            # ends with a forward slash.
        else
            input += '/'
        end 
    end
    input.gsub!('\\', '/')
return input
end
```

Comment: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/135748 - Looks like lots of helpful suggestions there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dir.glob` returns an empty array if there are no matches; check its length.

Also, you say the input should be backslashy, but are checking for a forward slash. That aside, idiomatically you're probably write that as:

```
input += '/' unless input[-1..1] == '/'
```

Comment: The empty array thing has me on the right path I think. And the advice about the cleaner code is definitely helpful. Much more readable that way!

Comment: @thekungfuman Hopefully more than "on the right way" since with that change the code works as-is.

Comment: Managed to get it working by comparing it to the empty array like you suggested. Thanks very much.

Comment: @thekungfuman Don't compare it to an empty array, check its length.

Comment: @thekungfuman Actually, the `any?` function would be better; sorry--wasn't thinking.

Comment: I realized since I need to know if the directory exists AND has files of a certain type in it, isn't checking for the files enough, since it can't contain the files if it doesn't exist?